# When classloader loads interfaces in java?

Tags: java, interface, classloader

I am trying to understand how classloader works. I have built a simple test application and running in -verbose:class mode. I have an interface and a class.

Interface

```
public interface Animal {

    int h = 8;
}
```

Class

```
public class Elephant implements Animal {

    static int staticInt;

    static void initTest(){
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    }
}
```

I am running the below command in the main application and get the expected output. Both interface and class are loaded in the memory, since i have accessed to a static field of the Elephant class

```
int i = Elephant.staticInt;

[0.795s][info][class,load] classloader.test.Animal source: file:/C:/study/class-loader/out/production/class-loader/
[0.795s][info][class,load] classloader.test.Elephant source: file:/C:/study/class-loader/out/production/class-loader/
```

When i run the below code i see that only the Animal class is loaded which i also expect.

```
Animal.class.getClassLoader();

[0.864s][info][class,load] classloader.test.Animal source: file:/C:/study/class-loader/out/production/class-loader/
```

The problem is when i only access to the field of the interface i dont see the class loading output in my console. Are interfaces loaded differently ? How can i access to the integer value if it is not loaded? I could not find anything on the subject.

```
//When i run the below code i only get the value of the integer but not the class loading info 
System.out.println("The integer is "  + Animal.h);

The integer is 8
```

Note: All three cases were run seperately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java compiler inlines static final constants (`int h` in the interface is implicitly static and final), so your code effectively compiles to this:

```
System.out.println("The integer is "  + 8);
```

As you see, there is no reference to `Animal` any more. That's why it's not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

> Are interfaces loaded differently ?

Actually, no.  (You would get the same thing if you tried to access a `public static final` field of a class in another class.)

> How can I access to the integer value if it is not loaded?

You are referring to a field that is initialized with a constant expression.  The expression is evaluated at compile time, and the value is inserted into the bytecodes at the point that it is used.  Therefore, the use of *this* interface field does not trigger class loading.

The relevant sections of the JLS are:

- [9.3.1. Initialization of Fields in Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3.1)
- [12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)
- [15.28. Constant Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember this exactly, but I'm thinking it's because h is "public static final" in an interface. This means the constant is simply redefined internally in the Elephant.class bytecode, if I'm not mistaken, which means Animal is not needed at this point.

Comment: But Elephant is also not loaded in the third case

Comment: True, the constant is inlined in your Main class, as described by ZhekaKozlov.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what's happening when looking directly at the bytecode. With the example class:

```
public class Test {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(Animal.h);
    }
}
```

And it's bytecode (only showing `test()` for brevity):

```
  // access flags 0x1
  public test()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 3 L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    BIPUSH 8
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (I)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 4 L1
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE this LTest; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

You can see the `BIPUSH 8` instruction defined in the [java bytecode instruction listings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) with the description:

> push a byte onto the stack as an integer value

The value `8` is not loaded from anywhere, because it's a compile time constant and thus directly resolved at compile time, as it will never change.

Thus your `Animal` class will never be loaded by the class loader.

Also when using a decompiler (I use IntelliJ, which uses Fernflower), the resulting `Test` class looks like this:

```
public class Test {
    public Test() {
    }

    public void test() {
        System.out.println(8);
    }
}
```